# Cross platform way to build DMG file using ANT?

Tags: java, macos, deployment, package

I'm looking to deploy my Java app to MacOS, and the most common way seems to be a DMG file that contains a symlink to the application folder and your application (and you drag one onto the other.)

I'd like to be able to generate the DMG file cross platform via ant - specifically on Windows (though a cross platform Java ANT task would be best!) The only options I've thus found are from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform) and either fall under the category of paid applications or Linux commands.

If not, are there any sensible alternatives to a DMG file that would be easier, but still provide the same (or very similar) level of user familiarity? By sensible, I definitely don't mean alternatives like "Just build on a Mac"!

EDIT: I'm currently using JarBundler, but I've yet to find a JavaApplicationStub that works alongside Java 7 (my application requires Java 7 unfortunately which is a bit of a stumbling block it seems!)

Comment: After googling, I found something http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/

Comment: @eee Unless I'm missing something, that link only shows the process using hdiutil, which isn't cross platform.

Comment: You are right; I've missed your requirement to compile on Windows. Check this out: http://code.google.com/p/limegreen/

Comment: @eee Same issue again - see question 4 here: http://code.google.com/p/limegreen/wiki/FAQ

Comment: oh my...you are out of luck again

Comment: Ok, I hope it will be in the right path. JarBundler seems to work on Windows, Linux and MacOSX...it can create Mac OSX application (.APP) http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarbundler/

Comment: @eee I should have clarified, that's currently what I'm using - but I can't find a JavaApplicationStub that works with Java 7 to include (which is what I need.)

Comment: Yeah, I've realized your problem when I look into the tool. Maybe, you can copy the Java stub folder which is installed in MacOSX and bring it into Windows just to make the tool work. I am not sure whether it works or not...but you can try. The best is to ask the tool author himself.

Comment: @eee I might contact the author, good idea. I've tried copying the stub for Java 6 but no dice there unfortunately.

Comment: There is a way of creating dmg on Linux. See here: http://serverhorror.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/create-dmg-images-for-os-x-on-linux/
You can combine this solution with limegreen

Answer (score -1):

Check this out for building Mac apps from Java 7:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Comment: Gave you a downvote on this one. I believe the OP very clearly asks for something cross-platform, i.e. create a DMG (for deployment on Mac) but do it on a non-Mac platform. The Oracle tools [require you to execute the build on the platform which is your target deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGJFJJI). (which is why I haven't heard of many people actually using these tools from Oracle)