# DMG processing on linux (centos)

Tags: linux, macos

Need to create a DMG file on linux environement, an alternative to hdiutil exist (not found yet as apple owns ht copyright!) ? Or is there an alternative to packageMaker (osx) on linux ? Need to deploy a mac app from a java build process  , maybe a ".pkg"  could be insteresting ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend:

- http://slopjong.de/2013/01/22/mount-apple-disk-images-dmg-in-linux/
- [How to build a dmg Mac OS X file (on a non-Mac platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)

For example:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/foo.dmg bs=1M count=64
mkfs.hfsplus -v ThisIsFoo /tmp/foo.dmg
```