# Convert python script to dmg program from windows

Tags: python, ios, py2exe

I have a Python script I would like to transform into an executable for Windows and a dmg file to be run on Apple computers. For the Windows systems I have found py2exe (only valid for Windows) and for the Apple ones py2app (it can only be run on Io systems).

My question is whether there is some way to create a dmg file of the Python script running a program from a Windows system (even though the program cannot be run). Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wait, isn't dmg just a disk image with the files inside?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a dmg Mac OS X file (on a non-Mac platform)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)