# Creating a mac app which calls a shell script, but developing in ubuntu

Tags: macos, dmg, .app

I have a shell script, and a tarball.  The shell script unpacks the tarball, and makes use of the files inside of for performing a task.  I need to make this accessible on mac laptops, but in such a way that there is either a .app or .dmg file that when clicked, ultimately calls that shell script.  I found several utilities, that can do this (create such an .app file), such as Platypus, or Appify.  However, these require Mac to build the file.  The thing is, I must package the .app/.dmg file, in an Ubuntu environment.

Is there any good software for creating a dmg or app file which call a shell script when clicked, but such that the software which can be run in Ubuntu (just for the purpose of creating the file)?

Comment: Is this *just* a command-line tool, or is there a front-end to it? If you're building a `.app` it's expected that's actually a graphical front-end, not some command-line thing. If you have command-line tools, build a proper installer `.pkg`. You may not be able to construct such a thing on Ubuntu, at least not without running a copy of macOS inside a VM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a dmg Mac OS X file (on a non-Mac platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)

Comment: this will have a front end component as well yes.  Ah yes I thought of running macOS in a VM but my understanding was that was difficult.  I might just have to find another way around..

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question but an workaround that might be acceptable if you can't find a better solution.

First, a zip file will automatically extract its content if you double click it in OS X so

```
tar -cvzf your_filename.zip ...
```

would create a file that can be easily extracted.

Secondly, if you create a shell script that has the extension .command, but otherwise is like any shell script, it can be run from OS X by double clicking on it (by opening a terminal and executing it there), it would mean an extra manual step for the user but like I said, this is a workaround :)
If you create a .command file, remember to make it executable.